# SCDF pipeline is breaking due to Kafka missing configuration

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-dataflow

We are running a stream data pipeline which is triggered by a Kafka topic (AWS-MSK), and while it is running successfully suddenly it breaks throwing the following exception. When I destroy and recreate it it's working fine until it breaks again.

```
org.springframework.kafka.listener.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener failed; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.MessageDeliveryException: Dispatcher has no subscribers for channel 'application.transactionProcessor-in-0'.; nested exception is org.springframework.integration.MessageDispatchingException: Dispatcher has no subscribers, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=byte[77], headers={kafka_offset=191, kafka_consumer=org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer@3ea3db9e, deliveryAttempt=3, kafka_timestampType=CREATE_TIME, kafka_receivedPartitionId=0, kafka_receivedTopic=aws-db4.BW3.INT_TRANS, kafka_receivedTimestamp=1661930907011, contentType=application/json, kafka_groupId=anonymous.6d66497c-d3fe-4109-9a7a-39b5aaddf974}], failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=byte[77], headers={kafka_offset=191, kafka_consumer=org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer@3ea3db9e, deliveryAttempt=3, kafka_timestampType=CREATE_TIME, kafka_receivedPartitionId=0, kafka_receivedTopic=aws-db4.BW3.INT_TRANS, kafka_receivedTimestamp=1661930907011, contentType=application/json, kafka_groupId=anonymous.6d66497c-d3fe-4109-9a7a-39b5aaddf974}]
at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.decorateException(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2683) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.4.jar:2.8.4]
at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeOnMessage(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2649) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.4.jar:2.8.4]
at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeOnMessage(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2609) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.4.jar:2.8.4]
at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2536) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.4.jar:2.8.4]
at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeWithRecords(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2427) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.4.jar:2.8.4]
at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2305) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.4.jar:2.8.4]
at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1979) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.4.jar:2.8.4]
at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeIfHaveRecords(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1364) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.4.jar:2.8.4]
at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.pollAndInvoke(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1355) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.4.jar:2.8.4]
at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1247) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.4.jar:2.8.4]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.MessageDeliveryException: Dispatcher has no subscribers for channel 'application.transactionProcessor-in-0'.; nested exception is org.springframework.integration.MessageDispatchingException: Dispatcher has no subscribers, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=byte[77], headers={kafka_offset=191, kafka_consumer=org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer@3ea3db9e, deliveryAttempt=3, kafka_timestampType=CREATE_TIME, kafka_receivedPartitionId=0, kafka_receivedTopic=aws-db4.BW3.INT_TRANS, kafka_receivedTimestamp=1661930907011, contentType=application/json, kafka_groupId=anonymous.6d66497c-d3fe-4109-9a7a-39b5aaddf974}]
at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:76) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.10.jar:5.5.10]
at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:317) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.10.jar:5.5.10]
at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:272) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.10.jar:5.5.10]
at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:187) ~[spring-messaging-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:166) ~[spring-messaging-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47) ~[spring-messaging-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:109) ~[spring-messaging-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.MessageProducerSupport.sendMessage(MessageProducerSupport.java:216) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.10.jar:5.5.10]
at org.springframework.integration.kafka.inbound.KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.sendMessageIfAny(KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.java:397) ~[spring-integration-kafka-5.5.10.jar:5.5.10]
at org.springframework.integration.kafka.inbound.KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.access$300(KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.java:83) ~[spring-integration-kafka-5.5.10.jar:5.5.10]
at org.springframework.integration.kafka.inbound.KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter$IntegrationRecordMessageListener.onMessage(KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.java:454) ~[spring-integration-kafka-5.5.10.jar:5.5.10]
at org.springframework.integration.kafka.inbound.KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter$IntegrationRecordMessageListener.onMessage(KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.java:428) ~[spring-integration-kafka-5.5.10.jar:5.5.10]
at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RetryingMessageListenerAdapter.lambda$onMessage$0(RetryingMessageListenerAdapter.java:125) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.4.jar:2.8.4]
at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.doExecute(RetryTemplate.java:329) ~[spring-retry-1.3.2.jar:na]
at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.execute(RetryTemplate.java:255) ~[spring-retry-1.3.2.jar:na]
at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RetryingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(RetryingMessageListenerAdapter.java:119) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.4.jar:2.8.4]
at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RetryingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(RetryingMessageListenerAdapter.java:42) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.4.jar:2.8.4]
at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeOnMessage(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2629) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.4.jar:2.8.4]
... 11 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.integration.MessageDispatchingException: Dispatcher has no subscribers
at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:139) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.10.jar:5.5.10]
at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:106) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.10.jar:5.5.10]
at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:72) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.10.jar:5.5.10]
... 28 common frames omitted
```